# How to write a SQL query for the below scenario

Tags: sql

Sales

```
order id : 1(primary key)
Billing address id -250
Shipping address id -285
```

Address table has the below entries

```
id :250
Addressline1 : XXX
Addressline2 :YYY

id :285
Addressline1 : AAA
Addressline2 :BBB
```

How to write a query to retrieve the `order id, billing address, shipping address` in a single query ?

Comment: This is basic stuff... read about SQL joins here : http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp 

Tell us what have you tried and what error are you getting

Answer (score 1):

Use the following query with join. The below is a sample code.

```
select order.orderid,
       ad1.Addressline1,
       ad1.Addressline2,
       ad2.Addressline1,
       ad2.Addresslinne2 
from order
join address ad1 on ad1.id=order.billingaddressid
join address ad2 on ad2.id=order.shippingaddressid
```

Comment: Is there any website to get various complex scenarios and sql queries for it? If you can share with us then it ll be helpful for us to learn more on sql

Answer (score 0):

You can join to the `address` table multiple times (this uses an `outer join` -- depends on potential `null` values):

```
select s.id, 
     billing.Addressline1,
     shipping.Addressline1
from sales s
    left join address billing on s.billingaddressid = billing.id
    left join address shipping  on s.shippingaddressid = shipping.id
```

- [A Visual Explanation of SQL Joins](http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/)

Comment: Thanks !!Is there any website to get various complex scenarios and sql queries for it? If you can share with us then it ll be helpful for us to learn more on sql